# Rebus, send message to Services Bus Azure DLQ

Tags: azureservicebus, rebus

Is there any way to send a Message to a DLQ in Service Bus Azure?

I have tried

```cs
await bus.Advanced.TransportMessage.Deadletter(errorDetails: "Let's hope it works");
```

but it didn't work. I assume this method send the message to the Rebus' QueueError, if so, is there any way to move the messages from this QueueError to the DLQ?

Comment: What’s the purpose of DLQ when the middleware provides an error queue?

Comment: @SeanFeldman Rebus' error queue is on memory which means we will lose everything if the application turns off for some reason. Also having the failed messages in a DLQ from azure allow us to reprocess all these message easily

Comment: If you're using ASB, the error queue will be an ASB queue, not in-memory. See [documentation](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Automatic-retries-and-error-handling). You won't lose anything. I'm still not clear what’s the purpose of DLQ when the middleware provides an error queue?

Comment: @Omar no, Rebus' error queue is NOT in memory! Rebus' error queue is an ordinary queue, which you can inspect in Azure Service Bus Explorer just as any other queue.

Comment: @Omar and Rebus is designed in a way that ensures that you willl NOT lose your messages, no matter how things fail – it maintains a strict at-least-once delivery guarantee throughout 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method call

```cs
await bus.Advanced.TransportMessage.Deadletter(errorDetails: "Let's hope it works");
```

will move the message currently being handled to Rebus' error queue. Rebus' error queue is an ordinary queue called "error", which it will automatically create when started.

The reason Rebus does not use Azure Service Bus' deadletter queue, is that if it did, it would behave differently when running on ASB compared to all other transports, since ASB's built-in deadletter queue works in a slightly different way that an ordinary queue.

E.g. using an ordinary queue called "error" means that you can start Rebus up with "error" as its input queue and have it consume the failed messages, because it's really just normal messages sitting in a normal queue (they just happen to have error details attached in a special header).

I hope it's more clear now.

--

UPDATE: Here's how it looks when checking out the queues in the Azure Portal

[image: Screenshot of the queues of Rebus' test ASB instance]

(in this case showing Rebus' test namespace that has a dead-letter queue called "error" currently containing one failed message)

Comment: Hello, we managed to solve the problem since our goal was to have final retries, meaning, the ability to decide when not to retry and send the message to the DLQ. We resolved this by using the IFailFastException. (see next reply)

Comment: However, now I'm curious and would like to know more. Why didn't it send to the ASB DLQ when I used the method? In fact, because I didn't see any change in the DLQ, I assumed that the error queue created by Rebus was in-memory. I don't know if you could update your post with some more information; I can't understand what that Rebus error queue is, how it's used, or why the data isn't lost (or rather, where in ASB that data ends up). Thank you very much for your message! :)

Comment: Hi @Omar, Rebus uses another queue called "error" as the dead-letter queue. It's a normal queue - just look at your ASB queues, and you'll find it right there.

Comment: I've updated my answer and added a screenshot. 